# How can I snapshot all Cargo compiler inputs for auditing on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, rust, rust-cargo

I am using Rust to cross compile a CLI.

An issue I am having is that typically the Rust compiler only works flawlessly when it compiles for the same OS/arch as the host it is running on (otherwise there are missing components, e.g. dynamic libs or compiler toolchains).

I want to release a binary that I have compiled on my Mac, but I want to be able to archive all inputs so that I can recreate the build for any future security audits.

For Linux I am using Docker containers which snapshot all files used as input to the `cargo build` process.

But for my Mac I have no idea how to isolate the cargo install, or what other toolchains or dynamic libs it may be calling out to.

Thanks

Comment: Does `cargo build --verbose` or `cargo build -vv` give you the information you're looking for?

Comment: @Aiden4 Not really, as I am looking to snapshot all inputs - this would include binary programs that are used as part of the compile (dynamic libraries like Open SSL, or C or C++ toolchains installed)

Comment: Does the output of [`cargo build --message-format=json`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/external-tools.html#json-messages) contain the information you are looking for? It should have information on both native and rust dependencies used.